# cakephp upload file option does not get properties of filename

Tags: php, cakephp, phpexcel

I m trying to upload xlsx file in cakePHP

View code

```
echo $this->Form->create('Program', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->file('Program.avatar');
echo $this->Form->submit();
```

Controller code

```
$inputFileName = $this->request->data['Program']['avatar'];
var_dump($inputFileName);
```

Issue is output of var_dump does not give properties of file which i would like to use it for PHPExcel plugin. Instead $inputFileName outputs "string 'import.xlsx' (length=11)", due to which i m unable to use it for IOFactory

Could anyone please let me know where I m going wrong on this.

Thank you.

Comment: It gives output similar to previous array
  'avatar' => string 'import.xlsx' (length=11), it would not help much. Anyways thanks for reviewing

Answer (score 1):

If you use var_dump it will put extra information into the output (as it is dumping the variables).

If you simply use

```
echo $inputFileName;
```

or

```
return $inputFileName;
```

These will return only the filename, you can also handle this directly through the $_FILES array or to stick with the CakePHP way you can simply get the information of the file from $this->request->data as explained here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#validating-uploads

Comment: Thanks for responding, based on your input i have tried below code in view    echo $form->create('Program', array('action' => 'importexcel', 'type' => 'file'));
   echo $form->file('file');
   echo $form->submit(__('Upload', true)); and in Controller i have called it like this    $inputFileName = $this->request->data['Program']; But    print_r ($inputFileName); still done not give me full array, it just gave output as Array ( [Program] => import.xlsx ) . Can you please provide correct syntax to be used for calling in Controller

Comment: Please update your original post with the code not in comments

Comment: Use $_FILES as I explained above, the code in that CakeDC link is a little outdated (I have updated the link with a better one for what you want) so if you cant work out what you have to do from that it is probably better to just keep it simple. You should maybe look into using XDebug so you can see what data you have available at any one point!

Comment: I have added debug on $inputfilename it gives me only filename. So i m back to same problem. Any help in resolving the issue will be greatly helpful for me thank you

Comment: have you even read my comments above? in your Controller do debug($_FILES)